# React-Native and the Parse SDK

Tags: parse-platform, sdk, react-native

I am new to react-native and wanted to know if I can reuse the JS SDK with react-native even though the JS SDK may reference DOM? Are there plans for a react-native friendly version of the Parse SDK in the works?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used fetch method and connected to Parse using the RESTgul API. Here are some links that may help you:

- https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide
- http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch